# Inspecting intermediate values in a neural network

Tags: neural-networks

Basically one creates a `NetChain` of several layers, trains it and by evaluating `model[testdata]`, the prediction can be obtained. However, I am unable to obtain the intermediate values of the prediction, i.e., the output after each layer with basic function usages.

I have tried to build a `NetGraph`, creating a path from the node I want to inspect to another output, but it didn't work since all the outputs must be a part of training process.

I also tried `NetExtract`, and succeed only with simple structured networks. Here is an small example to illustrate my question.

```
(*build an RNN with simple layers*)
test = NetInitialize[
  NetChain[{LongShortTermMemoryLayer[5], SequenceLastLayer[], 
    LinearLayer[2], SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> {"Varying", 3}], 
  Method -> "Random"];
(*make a prediction*)
test[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3}}]
(*{0.299767, 0.700233}*)
(*use net extract and manually evaluate the model*)
ComposeList[NetExtract[test, #] & /@ Range[4], {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3}}]
(*{{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 
   3}}, {{0.279698, -0.0118263, -0.000721162, -0.142595, \
-0.00157304}, {0.244337, -0.149762, -0.000606668, -0.138503, \
-0.0288229}}, {0.244337, -0.149762, -0.000606668, -0.138503, \
-0.0288229}, {-0.638368, 0.210041}, {0.299767, 0.700233}}*)
```

In my actual problem, I need to capture the probabilities of a classifier before it is encoded to classes. `ClassifierMeasurements` works for single-output classifiers, but mine outputs a sequence of classes and can't be processed by that function.

Is there a convenient/native way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also tap off the intermediate layers by attaching output ports. For example

```
net = NetInitialize@
  NetGraph[{LongShortTermMemoryLayer[5], SequenceLastLayer[], 
    LinearLayer[2], 
    SoftmaxLayer[]}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 
     1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NetPort["Output"], 1 -> NetPort["layer1"], 
    2 -> NetPort["layer2"], 3 -> NetPort["layer3"]}, 
   "Input" -> {"Varying", 3}]
```

[image]

Then

```
net[{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3}}]
(* <|"Output" -> {0.716093, 0.283907}, 
 "layer1" -> {{0.0242801, 0.00128676, -0.220564, 0.010784, 
    0.369972}, {-0.0774157, 0.0137297, -0.456915, 0.0116218, 
    0.665373}}, 
 "layer2" -> {-0.0774157, 0.0137297, -0.456915, 0.0116218, 0.665373}, 
 "layer3" -> {0.748411, -0.176754}|> *)
```

You don't have to use all the output ports in the training process. For example, this uses only the original input and output ports:

```
NetTrain[net, {<|"Input" -> {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3}}, 
   "Output" -> {0.5281522274017334`, 0.471847802400589`}|>},
   "Output" -> MeanSquaredLossLayer[]]
```

This works for `NetGraph` as well.

---

Here is a complete example using MNIST where the 10th layer is tapped off:

```
lenet = NetGraph[{
   ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
   ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
   FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 10, 
   SoftmaxLayer[]}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 
    1 -> 2 -> 
      3 -> 4 -> 
        5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> NetPort["Output"], 
   10 -> NetPort["layer10"]},
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}], 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}]
  ]

trainingData2 = <|"Input" -> #[[1]], "Output" -> #[[2]]|> & /@ 
   RandomSample[trainingData, 1000];

trained = NetTrain[lenet, trainingData2, "Output" -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"]]

trained[trainingData2[[1, 1]]]
(* <|"Output" -> 5, 
 "layer10" -> {-2.34726, -9.10603, -0.501655, -0.602975, 0.368083, 
   6.48835, -5.21255, -1.2072, 1.68743, 5.18232}|> *)
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but @happyfish said in the question: *I have tried to build a NetGraph, creating a path from the node I want to inspect to another output, but it didn't work since all the outputs must be a part of training process*. Isn't that what you're doing?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part in the first place. I've added the corrections.

Comment: `"Output" -> MeanSquaredLossLayer[]` that's the part I missed. The documentation says `"port"->losslayer compute loss from one output of a multi-output net`, which is not clear about what's used to train. Your elaboration revealed its actual usage and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried xslittlegrass's solution, But it didn’t work and I got error massages: OptionValue::nodef "Unknown option \!\(\"Output\"\) for NetTrain NetTrain::missinslot "Specification for slot \!\(\"layer5\"\) is missing. Any ideas ? I'm using Mathematica 11.3 Tnank you!

Comment: Please open a new question with your details.

Answer (score 6):

Not really "convenient", but you can get the layers of a `NetChain` using `Normal`:

```
net = NetInitialize@NetChain[{3, Ramp, 4, Ramp, 1}, "Input" -> "Real"];
layers = Normal[net]
```

and then construct a `NetGraph` with the same layers, and an output port for each layer:

```
g = NetGraph[layers,
  Join[
   (* connections between adjacent layers *)
   # -> # + 1 & /@ Range[Length[layers] - 1],
   (* output ports *)
   # -> NetPort[StringTemplate["Layer_``"][#]] & /@ 
    Range[Length[layers]]
   ]]
```

Result:

```
net[1]
```

> {0.168289}

```
g[1]
```

> <|"Layer_1" -> {-0.792354, 0.213135, 0.565724}, 
>    "Layer_2" -> {0., 0.213135, 0.565724}, 
>    "Layer_3" -> {-0.422488, 0.126484, 0.000964101, 0.0990122}, 
>    "Layer_4" -> {0., 0.126484, 0.000964101, 0.0990122}, 
>    "Layer_5" -> {0.168289}|>

Comment: Thanks! I have got your point. Before checking your answer, I will wait some more hours to see if someone knows (or there exists) some "builtin" functions to do this.

Comment: @happyfish: Absolutely. I also hope there's a simpler solution, one that works for `NetGraph` networks, too.